# Condition statement if there are data that can be clear out in the sheet using VBA code

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, spreadsheet

I am currently trying to make an if condition statement and link it with a form-control button that would check if there were data in the sheets, it will clear out all the data and if there are none, it will pop-up a message box saying **there is no data to erase**. However, I'm still learning and new to VBA, so I don't know where I am getting it wrong. **The buttons stopped working after I edited the code like this**. Any kind of advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance! Below is my code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RndGenerator()
    Randomize 'To initialize RND function
    'number < 0
    Range("A1", "A100") = Rnd(-1)
    Range("B2", "B100") = Rnd(-1)
    Range("C3", "C100") = Rnd(-1)
    
    'number = 0
    Range("D4", "D100") = Rnd(0)
    Range("E5", "E100") = Rnd(0)
    Range("F6", "F100") = Rnd(0)
    
    'number > 0
    Range("G7", "G100") = Rnd(1)
    Range("H8", "H100") = Rnd(1)
    Range("I9", "I100") = Rnd(1)
End Sub

Sub ClearAllCells()
    Dim cS As Boolean
    cS = Cells.Select
    If cS = True Then Cells.Clear
    Else
    MsgBox "There are no data to erase!"
    End If
End Sub
```

If I only use like this without any if condition, the button works just fine. I just want to experiment more and understand more about how VBA works.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RndGenerator()
    Randomize 'To initialize RND function
    'number < 0
    Range("A1", "A100") = Rnd(-1)
    Range("B2", "B100") = Rnd(-1)
    Range("C3", "C100") = Rnd(-1)
    
    'number = 0
    Range("D4", "D100") = Rnd(0)
    Range("E5", "E100") = Rnd(0)
    Range("F6", "F100") = Rnd(0)
    
    'number > 0
    Range("G7", "G100") = Rnd(1)
    Range("H8", "H100") = Rnd(1)
    Range("I9", "I100") = Rnd(1)
End Sub

Sub ClearAllCells()
    Cells.Clear
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clear Range If Not Empty

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const RG_ADDRS As String _
    = "A1:A100,B2:B100,C3:C100;" _
    & "D4:D100,E5:E100,F6:F100;" _
    & "G7:G100,H8:H100,I9:I100"
Private Const RND_ARGS As String = "-1;0;1"

Sub RndGenerator()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

    Dim rgAddrs() As String: rgAddrs = Split(RG_ADDRS, ";")
    Dim rndArgs() As String: rndArgs = Split(RND_ARGS, ";")

    Dim aData(), arg As Range, n As Long, r As Long, rndArg As Long

    For n = 0 To UBound(rgAddrs)
        For Each arg In ws.Range(rgAddrs(n)).Areas
            rndArg = CLng(rndArgs(n))
            aData = arg.Value
            For r = 1 To UBound(aData, 1)
                'Randomize
                aData(r, 1) = Rnd * rndArg
            Next r
            arg.Value = aData
        Next arg
    Next n

End Sub

Sub ClearCells()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rgAddr As String: rgAddr = Join(Split(RG_ADDRS, ";"), ",")
    
    Dim IsNotCleared As Boolean
    IsNotCleared = Application.CountA(ws.Range(rgAddr)) > 0
    
    If IsNotCleared Then
        ws.Range(rgAddr).Clear
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no data to erase!", vbExclamation
    End If

End Sub
```